# Postgres uses seq scan instead of index only scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I created an index on the table ref_class:

```
CREATE INDEX ref_class_recl_iid_rcl_ivaleur_idx
    ON ref_class (rcl_iid,rcl_ivaleur);
```

When i execute a select to retrieve the rcl_iid and the rcl_ivaleur, i expect that the optimizer will use the index above to make an index only scan. But, it uses a sequential scan.
The select query is the following:

```
select rcl_ivaleur from ref_class where rcl_iid = 1;
```

The execution plan used by Postgres is the following:

```
Seq Scan on ref_class  (cost=0.00..7.47 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.093 ms
Execution Time: 0.048 ms
  Rows Removed by Filter: 278
  Output: rcl_ivaleur
  Filter: (ref_class.rcl_iid = 1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: ```Execution Time: 0.048 ms``` what level of improvement are you expecting use of an index to have over this time?

Comment: I use this query as a sub query in a much complex query. This is why i am trying to use the index only scan

Answer (score 0):

After running the query below the optimizer picked the index only scan:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE ref_class;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a composite index so you need to use both the fields in the where clause  in the same order of fields `(rcl_iid,rcl_ivaleur)` you have created in the create index statement.Then only it will use index scan.